# Adjusting size of input to size of span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have various spans that turn into input boxes so i can edit them, every time i press a specific button. My problem is the CSS, that changes the entire layout of the table.

How can i solve this, so the table rows don't change, and the input boxes width and height are the exact same as the span's respective ones?

Here's my fiddle:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2D9FW/192/)

Here's the HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th  class="col-xs-6">Name</th>
    <th  class="col-xs-2" >Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span id="s1" class="editable-span col-xs-6">John</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span id="s2" class="editable-span col-xs-2">2345</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="s3" class="editable-span col-xs-2">Dave</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span id="s4" class="editable-span col-xs-2">5678</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="s5" class="editable-span col-xs-12 col-md-8">Sarah</span>
    </td>
    <td><span id="s6" class="editable-span col-xs-2">1987</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="edit_properties" class="col-xs-2">Edit</button>
<button id="unedit_properties" class="col-xs-2">Save</button>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$("#edit_properties").on("click", function() {
$('.editable-span').replaceWith(function() {
return $("<input>", {
  val: $(this).text(),
  type: "text",
  id: this.id,
  class: 'editable-input'
  });
 });
});

$("#unedit_properties").on("click", function() {
$('.editable-input').replaceWith(function() {
return $("<span>", {
  text: this.value,
  id: this.id,
  class: 'editable-span'
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: What should be the default `width` of `<span>`, `<input>` elements be?

Comment: @guest271314 it is not important. my main concern is that they have the same values

Answer (score 1):

Class "col-xs-6" missing when save:

```
$("#edit_properties").on("click", function() {
  $('.editable-span').replaceWith(function() {
    return $("<input>", {
      val: $(this).text(),
      type: "text",
      id: this.id,
      class: 'editable-input'
    });
  });
});

$("#unedit_properties").on("click", function() {
  $('.editable-input').replaceWith(function() {
    return $("<span>", {
      text: this.value,
      id: this.id,
      class: 'editable-span'
    });
  });
});
```

Updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/ersamrow/2D9FW/197/

Comment: The whole thing is still shifting to the right. And the width and height still aren't the same. can you please check on that?

Answer (score -1):

Try to fix height and width of span and input---

```
span
{
width:100px;
height:20px;
padding:2px;}
input
{
width:100px;
height:20px;
padding:2px;
}
```